# Ошибки "String cannot be converted to int" и "not a statement"

Tags: java

```
package main;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.util.Vector;

public class Restaurant extends Frame {

    private final TextField district;
    private final TextField adress;
    private final TextField phone;
    private final TextField time;
    private final TextField orderCost;
    private final TextField completeCost;
    private final TextField finalCost;
    private final TextArea orderList;
    private final TextArea bestList;
private final List Pizzas;
private String phonefind;

Vector<Order> queue = new Vector<>();
String[] districts = { "Выборгский", "Калининский", "Невский", "Петроградский", "Приморский" };
int[] delivery = { 200, 100, 450, 50, 550 };
int[] costs = { 250, 450, 400, 200, 330, 320, 200 };
int[] popularity = new int[7]; int totalCost = 0;
class Order {
String district, adress, phone, time, so; String[] meals;
int orderCost;
}
Restaurant(String title) { super(title); setLayout(null);

Label District = new Label("Район:"); Label Adress = new Label("Адрес:"); Label Phone = new Label("Телефон:");
Label Time = new Label("Время доставки:"); Label Meals = new Label("Меню:");
Label Order = new Label("Ваш заказ:"); Label Cost = new Label("Стоимость:");
Label deliveryCost = new Label("С доставкой:"); Label TotalCost = new Label("Выручка за день:"); Label Best = new Label("Лидеры продаж:");


District.setBounds(25, 50, 70, 20);
Adress.setBounds(25, 85, 70, 20);
Phone.setBounds(25, 120, 70, 20);
Time.setBounds(25, 150, 100, 20);
Meals.setBounds(25, 180, 70, 20);
Order.setBounds(30, 375, 80, 20);
Cost.setBounds(30, 535, 80, 20);
deliveryCost.setBounds(30, 570, 80, 20);
TotalCost.setBounds(290, 605, 120, 20);
Best.setBounds(320, 50, 100, 20);

add(District); 
add(Adress); 
add(Phone); 
add(Time); 
add(Meals); 
add(Order); 
add(Cost); 
add(deliveryCost); 
add(TotalCost); 
add(Best);

district = new TextField(); adress = new TextField(); phone = new TextField(); time = new TextField(); orderCost = new TextField(); finalCost = new TextField();
completeCost = new TextField();

district.setBounds(100, 50, 200, 20);
adress.setBounds(100, 85, 200, 20);
phone.setBounds(100, 120, 200, 20);
time.setBounds(130, 150, 170, 20);
orderCost.setBounds(120, 535, 180, 20);
finalCost.setBounds(120, 570, 180, 20);
completeCost.setBounds(410, 605, 180, 20);

add(district); 
add(adress); 
add(phone); 
add(time); 
add(orderCost); 
add(finalCost); 
add(completeCost);

orderList = new TextArea(); bestList = new TextArea();

orderList.setBounds(30, 400, 300, 120);
bestList.setBounds(320, 70, 300, 300);

add(orderList);
add(bestList);

Pizzas = new List(1, true); 
Pizzas.add("Пицца с грибами"); 
Pizzas.add("Пицца карбонара"); 
Pizzas.add("Пицца четыре вида сыра"); 
Pizzas.add("Пицца пеперони"); 
Pizzas.add("Пицца с пюре"); 
Pizzas.add("Пицца вегетарианская"); 
Pizzas.add("Пицца-крекер"); 
Pizzas.setBounds(30, 200, 270, 130); 
add(Pizzas);

Button createOrder = new Button("Заказать"); Button findOrder = new Button("Поиск");

createOrder.setBounds(30, 335, 135, 30);
findOrder.setBounds(165, 335, 135, 30);

add(createOrder);
add(findOrder);

createOrder.addActionListener(new makeOrder()); 
findOrder.addActionListener(new Find());

setSize(650, 650); 
setVisible(true); 
setResizable(false);

}
class makeOrder implements ActionListener {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Order order = new Order();
order.district = district.getText(); 
order.adress = adress.getText(); 
order.phone = phone.getText(); 
order.meals = Pizzas.getSelectedItems(); 
order.time = time.getText();
int[] pizzas = Pizzas.getSelectedIndexes(); String finalOrder = "";
for (int i = 0; i < order.meals.length; i++)
{order.orderCost += finalOrder +=costs[pizzas[i]]; // здесь ошибка "String cannot be converted to int"
order.meals[i] + " - " + costs[pizzas[i]]+ " руб." + "\n"; } // тут "not a statement"


order.so = finalOrder;
orderCost.setText(Integer.toString(order.orderCost));

order.so = finalOrder;
orderCost.setText(Integer.toString(order.orderCost));
boolean w=false;
for (int i = 0; i < districts.length; i++) {
if (districts[i].equals(order.district)) { order.orderCost += delivery[i];
finalOrder += "\n" + "Доставка - " + delivery[i] + " руб."; w=true;
}

}
if(!w){
order.orderCost += 700;
finalOrder += "\n" + "Доставка - 700 руб.";
}
 finalCost.setText(Integer.toString(order.orderCost)); 
 orderList.setText(finalOrder);
totalCost += order.orderCost; 
completeCost.setText(Integer.toString(totalCost)); 
orderList.append("\nВремя заказа :" + order.time); 
queue.add(order);
for (int i = 0; i < pizzas.length; i++) { popularity[pizzas[i]]++; }
String populars = "";
int maxPopularity = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < popularity.length; i++) {
if (popularity[i] > maxPopularity) maxPopularity = popularity[i];}

int k = 0;
for (int i = maxPopularity; i > 0; i--) {
if (k < 4) {
for (int j = 0; j < Pizzas.getItemCount(); j++) {
if (popularity[j] == i) {
populars += Pizzas.getItem(j) + "\n"; k++;}
}
}
}
bestList.setText(populars);
}
}
class Find implements ActionListener {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { phonefind = phone.getText();
queue.stream().filter((order) -> (order.phone.equals(phonefind))).map((order) -> {
    orderList.setText("");
        return order;
    }).map((order) -> {
        orderList.append("Район доставки: " + order.district);
        return order;
    }).map((order) -> {
        orderList.append("\nАдрес доставки: " + order.adress);
        return order;
    }).map((order) -> {
        orderList.append("\nТелефон заказчика: " + order.phone);
        return order;
    }).map((order) -> {
        orderList.append("\nВремя заказа: " + order.time);
        return order;
    }).map((order) -> {
        orderList.append("\n"+"\n"+order.so);
        return order;
    }).map((order) -> {
        finalCost.setText(Integer.toString(order.orderCost));
        return order;
    }).map((order) -> {
        boolean w=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < districts.length; i++) {
            if (districts[i].equals(order.district)) { order.orderCost -= delivery[i];
            }

        }       if(!w){



            order.orderCost -= 700;
        }       return order;
    }).forEachOrdered((order) -> {
        orderCost.setText(Integer.toString(order.orderCost));
    });
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Restaurant r = new Restaurant("Ресторан Папы Димы"); r.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ex) { System.exit(0);
}
});
}
}
```

Здравстуйте. Помогите исправить ошибки на строках 125(String cannot be converted to int) и 126(not a statement).

Comment: вы предлагаете отсчитывать что ли эти строки?

Comment: @pavlofff, Сейчас в любом нормальном редакторе есть подсчет строк. Вставьте и посмотрите.

Comment: Нет, просто на NetBeans указывает ошибки на этих строках и я не могу их исправить

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос и вставьте в него полный текст ошибок.

Comment: Указал ошибки в виде комментариев в коде

Comment: спасибо большое, но делать я этого конечно не буду и вряд ли найдется много желающих страдать подобным. Если вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли решить проблему именно вы должны приложить к этому какие то усилия, какиуказать где эти несчастные строки, например